# Show $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$ is continuous from $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n \rightarrow Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\mu$ is the map $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$ from $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$, ***I'm trying to show that this is continuous***(Assume product topology on $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n$).  I can see that I have to show that $\mu^{-1}(V) \in T_{\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n}$ if $V \in T_{\Bbb R^n}$.  This means showing ultimately (since showing an element is in a union means showing it's in one set of the union) that the inverse image of an open ball $B_{r_0}(x_0)$ can be written as a product of two open balls $B_{r_1}(x_1), B_{r_2}(x_2)$, which means showing that $$\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n: |z_0-(x + y)| \lt r_0 \}=$$ $$\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n : |x_1-x|\lt r_1 \text{ and } |x_2-y| \lt r_2\} $$ for some $x_1, r_1, x_2, r_2$.

Showing $\Leftarrow$ inclusion is simple by letting $x_1 + x_2 = z_0$ and letting $r_1=r_2 = \frac{r_0}{2}$ and using the triangle inequality,
but I'm having trouble showing forward inclusion.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: *"This means showing ultimately that the inverse image of an open ball $B_{r_0}(x_0)$ can be written as a product of two open balls $B_{r_1}(x_1), B_{r_2}(x_2)$"*: it does **not**.  It means showing that $\mu^{-1}(V)$ can be written as the union of such products.  For instance, in the case of $n = 1$, we'd like to be able to say that the open unit disk is an open set.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n$ has the product topology, then all open sets are of the form $U_1 \times U_2$.  So shouldn't $\mu^{-1}(V) = U_1 \times U_2$?

Comment: No. It is **not** the case that all open sets are of that form.  Check the definition more closely.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for recognizing that, I went back and re-read the definition.  So then, if $V = B_{r_0}(z_0)$, $A = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n : |z_0-(x+y)| \lt r_0\} = \bigcup_i (B_{r_i}(a_i) \times B_{p_i}(b_i)) = C$ is what I'm trying to prove.  But to show an element $(x,y)$ of $A$ is also an element of $C$, I would have to show there exists a specific product of open balls in $C$ that contains $(x,y)$, and from here I'm stuck as in the question.

Comment: I'm assuming it's a triangle inequality relationship, but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If you know how to show this is continuous by this or another way that would be appreciated.  I'm self learning this, so any help would be helpful.

Comment: Don't make it too complicated; use what you have: A metric, i.e. use the limit definition for continuity. Don't argue with sets only, unless you have nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ by $f(x,y) = x +y$. Let $B^n(f(x,y), \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ be a basic open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It suffices to give a basic open set $(x,y) \in B \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(B) \subset B^n (f(x,y),\epsilon)$. Let $B=B^n(x,\frac{\epsilon}{2}) \times B^n(y,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$, then for $(x_0, y_0) \in B$ we have $|x-x_0|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|y-y_0|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ thus $|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)| = |x+y - x_0-y_0| \leq |\frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}|=\epsilon$ and we have $f(B) \subset B^n (f(x,y),\epsilon)$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f_1$ from $\mathbb{R^n}×\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$ define by $f_1(x,y)=x$ for all $ x,y \in $$\mathbb{R^n}$ as $||f_1(x,y)-f_1(x',y')||\leq ||(x,y)-(x',y')||$ hence continuous. 
So similarly $f_2(x,y)=y$ for all $ x,y \in $$\mathbb{R^n}$ is continuous.
So $f(x,y)=f_1(x,y)+f_2(x,y)$ for all $ x,y \in $$\mathbb{R^n}$ is continuous.